# How to get the time of the minimum and maximum requests?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a table with product's sections.

```
__________________________________
| SECTION| PRICE |     TIME      |
|--------------------------------|
|  sec1  |   10  | 06-12-17 12:00|
|  sec2  |   20  | 06-12-17 12:01|
|  sec1  |   20  | 06-12-17 12:02|
|  sec1  |   30  | 06-12-17 12:03|
|  sec2  |   30  | 06-12-17 12:04|
----------------------------------
```

I need to have min, max and average for every section. I did it.

```
SELECT MAX(PRICE), MIN(PRICE), AVG(PRICE) FROM table1 GROUP BY SECTION;
```

I also need a sale time with a minimum and maximum price. If biggest sale was in different times I need any of them. How to get it in one table?

```
___________________________________________________________
| SECTION| MIN | MAX | AVG |  TIME OF MAX   |  TIME OF MIN |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
|  sec1  | 10  |  30 |  20 | 06-12-17 12:03 |06-12-17 12:00|
|  sec2  | 20  |  30 |  25 | 06-12-17 12:04 |06-12-17 12:01|
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using window functions without tripple join:

```
t=# WITH a as (
SELECT
      SECTION
    , MAX(PRICE) over w
    , MIN(PRICE) over w
    , AVG(PRICE) over w
    , TIME t, price
    , case when MAX(PRICE) over w = price then TIME end maxt
    , case when MIN(PRICE) over w = price then TIME end mint
FROM s154
WINDOW w as (partition by section)
)
select DISTINCT
      SECTION
    , MAX
    , MIN
    , AVG
    , max(maxt) over (partition by section)
    , min(mint) over (partition by section)
from a
;
 section  | max | min |         avg         |         max         |         min
----------+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------
   sec1   |  30 |  10 | 20.0000000000000000 | 2017-06-12 12:03:00 | 2017-06-12 12:00:00
   sec2   |  30 |  20 | 25.0000000000000000 | 2017-06-12 12:04:00 | 2017-06-12 12:01:00
(2 rows)
```

Also as Abelisto noted, [on larger data sets](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=b5fcf4bf9e7206c78f16a22bb0b1f0ae), `Filter`ing results before aggregation can significantly reduce the cost. So adding

```
where maxt is not null or mint is not null
```

to the end is recommended.

Comment: If add `where maxt is not null or mint is not null` to the final query it could be faster a bit (about two times in my tests).

Comment: true - filter should be fatser the aggregation - thanks!

Comment: PS: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=b5fcf4bf9e7206c78f16a22bb0b1f0ae

Comment: added to the answer. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Thank you very much. All I need.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something like Oracle `KEEP FIRST`, which can only be emulated in PostgreSQL with window functions:

```
select
  section,
  min(price),
  max(price),
  avg(price),
  max(case when rnk_max = 1 then time end) as time_of_max,
  max(case when rnk_min = 1 then time end) as time_of_min
from
(
  select 
    section, 
    price, 
    time,
    rank() over (partition by section order by price desc) as rnk_max,
    rank() over (partition by section order by price) as rnk_min
  from sections
) ranked
group by section;
```

I am using `RANK`, so you can get several records for a minimum or maximum price. With `max(case ...)` I'll take the newest date from the sets then.

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption**: Min and Max price can only happen in unique time.

Try this (I choose to write in easy to understand instead of efficient query):

```
SELECT      sq.*
            , tmin.time AS minTime
            , tmax.time AS maxTime
FROM        (
            SELECT      section
                        , MAX(price)    AS maxPrice
                        , MIN(price)    AS minPrice
                        , AVG(price)    AS avgPrice
            FROM        table1
            GROUP BY    section
        ) AS sq
    INNER JOIN table1 AS tmin
        ON tmin.section = sq.section
        AND tmin.price  = sq.minPrice
    INNER JOIN table1 AS tmax
        ON tmax.section = sq.section
        AND tmax.price  = sq.minPrice;
```